# Pomodoro timer in Python

Tags: python

I have recently started learning Python and tried writing a pomodoro timer program. I have written the `tasks()` function and it works fine but i don't know how to write `break` function that works together with `tasks()` function.

Things I have tried:

1. I tried writing the break function separate from tasks() function and called break function inside the tasks() function.
2. I have written the break code inside the tasks() function.
3. Define main function and written break function in it but nothing is working. I have tried to google 
   but could not find the answer.

I would be really thankful if someone can teach me how to integrate break function with tasks function.

```
import time

checkmark=0
def tasks():
    global checkmark
    carry_on='y'
    while carry_on=='y'or carry_on=='Y':
        min=0
        task=input('What task do you want to work on?')
        print('timer for ',task,' is 25 mins')
        start=input('Press Enter to start the timer.')
        while min!=1:
            time.sleep(60)
            min=min+1
        print('End of task')
        checkmark=checkmark+1
        print('Total check mark is ',checkmark)

def main():
    tasks()
    mins=0
    if checkmark <4:
        print('take a short break')
        while mins!=3:
            time.sleep(60)
            mins=mins+1
            print('break over')
    elif checkmark >=4:
        print('Take a long break')
        while mins !=10:
            time.sleep(60)
            mins=mins+1
        print('Break over')
    else:
        tasks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the break function supposed to do?

Comment: after completing each task the person is suppose to take small break. if tasks are more than 4 break is 10 to 15 mins long if task is less than 4 than break time is 3 to 5 mins.

Comment: Yes but suppose you were to write a function called "break" and you were to call it. What is supposed to happen in the program?

Comment: If you have tried to write code that implements the break feature and you want to know why it doesn’t work, please include it in the question.

Comment: Program is suppose to alternate between task timer and break timer. Task timer is 25 min long after its over break timer is suppose to start automatically in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `tasks()` and `breaks()` functions as foolows. ALso note that you had not taken any input from the user to carry on with the task or not. You can check the code below. Also I have defined a `total_mins` variable which keep tracks of total time worked on the task.

```
import time

checkmark = 0
total_mins = 0

def tasks(task):
    global checkmark
    global total_mins
    mins=0
    print('Timer for ',task,' is 25 mins.')
    start=input('Press Enter to start the timer.')
    while mins <= 25:
        time.sleep(60)
        mins = mins + 1
        total_mins += 1
        print(mins, " minutes work completed.")
    print('End of Pomodoro')
    checkmark += 1
    print('Total check mark is ',checkmark)


def breaks():
    global checkmark
    mins = 0
    if checkmark <4:
        print('Take a short break.')
        while mins!=3:
            time.sleep(60)
            mins = mins + 1
            print(mins, " minutes break completed.")
        print('Break over')

    elif checkmark >=4:
        print('Take a long break.')
        while mins !=10:
            time.sleep(60)
            mins = mins + 1
            print(mins, " minutes break completed.")
        checkmark = 0
        print('Break over.')


def main():
    carry_on = 'y'
    task=input('Welcome to Pomodoro Timer\n What task do you want to work on? ')
    while carry_on=='y'or carry_on=='Y':
        tasks(task)
        breaks()
        carry_on = input("Do you want ot carry on?(y/n)")

    print("End of task ",task,". \nTotal time worked was minutes ", total_mins, " minutes.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, there is a better way to do it though. I solved it for you according to your approach.